# Hypothetical scenario: Python standalone executable for future machine compatibility

Tags: python, windows, executable, pyinstaller

I have used Python (version 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32) and pyinstaller (version 3.3.1) to build a standalone executable for **only** windows OS usage. This executable runs perfectly every time it is called.

I want this application to be available and usable for future changes and releases of windows. Is it possible/likely that in future releases that this executable will stop functioning? If so, what exactly would be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's never going to be any firm guarantee that software built for an older operating system continues to work on any conceivable future operating system.  That's analogous to asking "Can you guarantee that every car everywhere will always support my carburetor?"

That's demonstrably false, but also patently absurd to ponder.  No one can tell you what will or won't change in future operating systems, or what might introduce a binary incompatibility for a script compiled in the past.